# We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (8.0.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 33.

You are strongly encouraged to update your project to use a newer
Android Gradle plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34.

If you are already using the latest version of the Android Gradle plugin,
you may need to wait until a newer version with support for compileSdk = 34 is available.

To suppress this warning, add/update
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties.

Need Help, anyone solution please

Answer (score 7):

When using gradle plugin 8.1.1 the warning goes away.
There are no release notes of gradle plugin 8.1.1, but looks like they added support for SDK 34

Comment: I am Already Using gridle plugin 8.1.1, but still face the problem

Comment: Did you also update gradle wrapper or just the plugin? I updated both and I don’t see the warning anymore, but it’s weird as it was supposed to be “fixed” in gradle plugin 8.3.0 which is still not final.

Comment: How to update Gridle Wrapper please ?

Answer (score 3):

I have been running into this issue using the newest version of Android Studio and Gradle 8.1. I set my Gradle version to 8.3 in File > Project Structure > Project > Gradle Version but the Android Upgrade Assistant will not allow me to update past 8.1.

My guess is that the current version of the Upgrade Assistant doesn't know exactly how to update your project safely to use a version of Gradle above 8.1 so we may have to wait for an Android Studio Update to resolve this warning. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: i appreciate your Valuable Comment
GOD BLESSED YOU BROTHER

Comment: no problem! if you wouldn't mind throwing an upvote on the post it would be much appreciated. best of luck out there

Answer (score 1):

Current stable release of Android Studio is build in with Gradle 8.0.2 with support up to 33. You can try beta release of Android Studio to get most up-to-date build-in tools.